# New Raspberry pi 3 startup issue. Rainbow+Blackscreen

Tags: boot, screen

I just bought my first raspberry pi 3. So first I connected with HDMI mouse and keyboard. I downloaded the latest version of noob from pi site and connected the pi3 to the 2amp mobile charger.

The first bootup went perfectly.  During the installation of noob os, pi3 just stopped working and showed me a black screen. Now its been three days. I have tried changing the memory card, updating power adapters, tried different OS. But I haven't succeeded.

On some OSs, pi3 shows me a rainbow screen then black or blinks two times green led or hangs at rainbow screen.
They issues have face during trying of different OS for pi three:
Even tried to change in config file.
Please help regard this issue if anyone faced.??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't think it is the power supply, SD Card, or HDMI cable, then I would try:

1. Format SD Card first with "SD Card Formatter".
2. Download a [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).  Unzip it, then burn it using [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).
3. Edit config.txt in Wordpad, add "boot_delay=1", save and 'eject' the card.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Too be fair, he said phone charger, not PSU. And we all know phone chargers make less than ideal PSUs. It will work, but you will have undervoltage errors all the time, because phone chargers are not made to be PSUs.